# How to display Map View inside Web View

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, android-mapview, android-webview

For my Android app, I am using maps forge to get a map, but map is in "map View". For header and footer design, I am using jquery. This is in "web view". So please help me how i can add this map view inside web view.

Comment: If you're aiming for a native Android app, you should have the map, header, and footer in native elements. So `MapView` for the map, and some type of `View` or `ViewGroup` for the header and footer, depending on what you want to do. Are you trying to do everything on the web? YOu need to provide more information and maybe pictures to indicate what you are asking.

Comment: Yes i need every thing in web view i am getting the map view from http://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/  , all my UI design is in html5 using jquery mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
 private WebView _webView;

    _webView = (WebView)_yourrelativelayourSrc.findViewById(R.id.layout_webview);

    _webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    _webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    _webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);

    _webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
            // Activities and WebViews measure progress with different scales.
            // The progress meter will automatically disappear when we reach 100%
            ((Activity) activity).setProgress(progress * 1000);
        }

    });

    // to handle its own URL requests :
    _webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    _webView.loadUrl("http://maps.google.com/maps?q=Pizza,texas&ui=maps");
```

Comment: if i use this code device full window map is displaying, Jquery header and footer (Web View)not visible

Comment: Please any one help me how to get web view and map view in same window.